# Error System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: '

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Hola compañeros espero me puedan apoyar con mi problema. El tema es que mi aplicación funciona bien, solo que ahora quiero encriptar la cadena de conexión y desencriptarla cuando sea necesario para peticiones a la BD. El problema es que no funciona con la siguiente instrucción que es para hacer mi Login:

```
Usuario usuarioLog = usuarioORM.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Usuario1 == usuario.Usuario1 && x.Contrasena == contraMayus && x.Estatus == "ALTA").FirstOrDefault();
```

y con las peticiones que hago con sqlcommand, me funciona muy bien como esta :

```
public static string ConvertirContra(string contraseña)
    {
        var cn = new Conexion();
        string texto = Desencriptar(cn.GetCadenaSql());
        string resultado;

        using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(texto))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.fnPassword('" + contraseña + "')", conexion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conexion.Open();
            resultado = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

saben el por que truena ahi en esa instrucción? Ya intente todas las opciones de la pregunta [respuestaStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243008/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-a)

Comment: no entiendo tu problema.. anda a veces y otras no?

Comment: Si, con las peticiones que hago con sqlCommand , las realiza muy bien pero cuando entra en la instruccion del login que esta realizada con entity, sale ese error, a la hora de que lo estoy probando ya con la cadena de conexion encriptada

Comment: o sea el problema es que ef no logra desencriptar la cadena... en donde de toda tu pregunta, esta todo eso especificado????